# How can I make and farm Demon Altars in a world generated without one?

Tags: terraria

I want a Demon Altar in a 0.3.0 world with no Demon Altars. How do I get one and farm it?  I've tried defeating the Wall of Flesh in another world, but there is a glitch and the guide doesn't reaspawn. The first world is in hard mode and it generated with no Demon Altars.

What can I do?

Comment: I'm really confused by everything here. What do you mean by "farming an altar"?

Comment: How did you get version 0.3.0?

Comment: Don't you mean 1.3.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Demon Altars can't be created, either by crafting or by enemy drops. They are purely from world generation. I don't recall a version of Terraria that didn't have Demon Altars, but if for whatever reason your world doesn't have any, you're out of luck. You'll have to create a new world to spawn them.

Side note: As for the guide respawning, make sure the new guide has a valid house to move into. Also, it can take a day or two (or three) before he actually respawns, it's kind of random. There might not be a bug at all, you just have to be patient.

Comment: If your world doesn't have Demon Altars it probably has Crimson Altars instead, which are functionally identical.